# how to interpret "Vorgang" and "wie folgt"?

Tags: meaning, passive, past-participle, interpretation

> Mann kann den Vorgang wie folgt darstellen.

This is the result of google translation.

> The process can be represented as follows. (A)

Is this correct? To me the German sentense sounds like

> The precedent can be placed there as followed. (as people followed the precedent) (B)

In A, *Vorgang* was interpreted as *the things that will come in the future*, but in B I interpreted it as *the things that happend previously in the past, or the thing people already did in the past*.

And in A, *wie folgt* was interpreted as *as follows(in the future)*, but I interpreted it as *as it was followed (or as people followed)(in the past)*.

Which one is correct, A or B?

Comment: Your second translation possibly mixes up "Vorgang" (process) and "Vorgänger" (predecessor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, Google Translate is correct.

I recommed against Google Translate and using [deepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Man%20kann%20den%20Vorgang%20wie%20folgt%20darstellen.) instead.

Now

> Man kann den Vorgang wie folgt darstellen.

(and likewise the English translation) does not make any indication about *when* the process is happening. I concede these are not the best examples to use with *Vorgang*, but let's ignore that for a moment.

> Wie ist die Französische Revolution damals abgelaufen? Man kann den Vorgang wie folgt darstellen....

*How did the French Revolution happen? We can depict the process as follows...*

> Wie funktioniert Mergesort? Man kann den Vorgang wie folgt darstellen

*How does merge sort work? We can illustrate the process as follows...*

> Wie wird der Brexit ablaufen? Man kann den Vorgang wie folgt darstellen

*How will Brexit unfold? We can describe the process as follows...*

Your interpretation (B) does not make much sense to me, it just seems like a wrong translation.

Comment: I see. I had missed the meaning of Vorgang as process and I had confused folgt with befolgt. By the way, It would be more helpful if the reader could see the interpretation for Man kann ~ darstellen in the thee examples. (we can describe the process as follows.) Thanks!

Comment: @ChanKim don't worry about confusing similiar words with prefixes. I have added a sample translation to each example. Better options might be available.